# How can I make a http request on swift with authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, http, request

[IOS ucs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAni.png)

I need to make a http request with authentication.
First I need to do a GET to a URL below:
http://209.97.133.56/api/ucs
But I need to do it with authentication.
To do it I need to put the follow token in some header

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjQ2Yjg2ZDNlZDI2Y2IwOGU2NDFhZTI3NjNmMWI0ZDEwODAwZWI0M2U4YjM5MThiMTQ0YmU5YWFjMzBhNGU1ZDdhMTI4ZjA1MDI2NGNkYWZhIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiNDZiODZkM2VkMjZjYjA4ZTY0MWFlMjc2M2YxYjRkMTA4MDBlYjQzZThiMzkxOGIxNDRiZTlhYWMzMGE0ZTVkN2ExMjhmMDUwMjY0Y2RhZmEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTgzNDQ1MDIsIm5iZiI6MTU1ODM0NDUwMiwiZXhwIjoxNTg5OTY2OTAyLCJzdWIiOiIzIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.LSsn172WUQqEzUf3wzq4lxgBL8pbKGqjJCpn0iEFPFQY6DhZCtcm4jHkqTC0FFMYrAA1n87LfdBeSvcdgWFsndD6MoKHFkZViqZXlUHDeyMmT-bVs2IrNSE9kGuaRQhz1rtys2KFbB2y4lq5w2BPhokPYvLc0nTwZ7oPTZKQlJkUi80PKDMP3LMUQpilc2cSE8FGe-d1UtMYUeseivwHcNee4knjfOUIsGl7_pV4knU6DYTWL8IMXfb3GjbBTagFRWfbjeqMMvtFVdZGfTxdeVoMqSgEQlA0W20GyJ3Ox4WuZAaODk4b7Q4cudR8vmPTSjvVU-IqB6_9wvtE3HUMEwiGazQRcmFtVqBYFPVIBHFWNBsWI2AbMxR_KSA6URzF-6qydj53yRqO41E88KQiWbHy29mb8BCoNvjR4gN9F97rE9j9Xpt-EsHK6QEqBOeoJixu8srDrgmYul4nWroRU6dQsFZjfZS4Vnm1LFF-ykOo0YVY08oRcV3LQTb8TsnS3RuQzlMifEhDajBPTsVyCyW9OkkTsi3N96E1VeRhyT0S08InczXeRV_K5BMdt7tvVAEMPoR4GCcHAR5e7924WVsbl9KmJ4ituf_FdCfBKdvcmErURIlCfZRELLC_8kNaT-04CG3Vj9_LrUb6eOcJrutawh60V_ITojWAxyF2LnQ

I came here to get some help, because I cannot do this.

```
import Foundation

public class UnidadeCurricularManager{
    private var ucs = [UnidadeCurricular]();


    init(){ 

        let json = "{ \"data\": [ { \"id\": \"201819S1911921391192161352\", \"unidadeCurricularId\": 18734, \"unidadeCurricularNome\": \"Algoritmos e Estruturas de Dados\", \"unidadeCurricularAbreviatura\": \"AED\", \"unidadeCurricularAtivo\": \"1\", \"unidadeCurricularIdMapSiges\": 9119213, \"anoCurricularId\": 3, \"anoCurricularNome\": \"2\", \"anoCurricularAtivo\": 1, \"anoCurricularIdMapSiges\": 2, \"periodoTempoId\": 5, \"periodoTempoNome\": \"1º Semestre\", \"periodoTempoAbreviatura\": \"1\", \"periodoTempoOrdem\": 1, \"periodoTempoAtivo\": 1, \"periodoTempoIdMapSiges\": \"S1\", \"numeroEstudante\": \"2140259\", \"idAnoLetivo\": 31, \"idUnidadeCurricular\": 18734, \"idEstadoInscricao\": 12, \"idAnoCurricular\": 3, \"numero_creditos\": 6 }, { \"id\": \"201819S1911921391192161352\", \"unidadeCurricularId\": 18735, \"unidadeCurricularNome\": \"Programação Avançada\", \"unidadeCurricularAbreviatura\": \"PA\", \"unidadeCurricularAtivo\": \"1\", \"unidadeCurricularIdMapSiges\": 9119213, \"anoCurricularId\": 3, \"anoCurricularNome\": \"2\", \"anoCurricularAtivo\": 1, \"anoCurricularIdMapSiges\": 2, \"periodoTempoId\": 5, \"periodoTempoNome\": \"1º Semestre\", \"periodoTempoAbreviatura\": \"1\", \"periodoTempoOrdem\": 1, \"periodoTempoAtivo\": 1, \"periodoTempoIdMapSiges\": \"S1\", \"numeroEstudante\": \"2140259\", \"idAnoLetivo\": 31, \"idUnidadeCurricular\": 18734, \"idEstadoInscricao\": 12, \"idAnoCurricular\": 3, \"numero_creditos\": 7 }, { \"id\": \"201819S1911921391192161352\", \"unidadeCurricularId\": 18735, \"unidadeCurricularNome\": \"Álgebra Linear\", \"unidadeCurricularAbreviatura\": \"AlgL\", \"unidadeCurricularAtivo\": \"1\", \"unidadeCurricularIdMapSiges\": 9119213, \"anoCurricularId\": 3, \"anoCurricularNome\": \"1\", \"anoCurricularAtivo\": 1, \"anoCurricularIdMapSiges\": 1, \"periodoTempoId\": 5, \"periodoTempoNome\": \"1º Semestre\", \"periodoTempoAbreviatura\": \"1\", \"periodoTempoOrdem\": 1, \"periodoTempoAtivo\": 1, \"periodoTempoIdMapSiges\": \"S1\", \"numeroEstudante\": \"2140259\", \"idAnoLetivo\": 31, \"idUnidadeCurricular\": 18734, \"idEstadoInscricao\": 12, \"idAnoCurricular\": 3, \"numero_creditos\": 7 } ] }";


        //URL
        let url = URL(string: "http://http://209.97.133.56/api/ucs")!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }

        task.resume()


        //JSON
        guard let data = json.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return
        }
        do {
            if let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String,Any>
            {
                if let dataArray = jsonDictionary["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for data in dataArray {

                            let ucIdMapSiges = data["unidadeCurricularIdMapSiges"] as! Int
                            let ucNome = data["unidadeCurricularNome"] as! String
                            let ucSigla = data["unidadeCurricularAbreviatura"] as! String
                            let anoCurricularIdMapSiges = data["anoCurricularIdMapSiges"] as! Int
                            let periodoNome = data["unidadeCurricularAbreviatura"] as! String
                            let codigoEstudante = data["numeroEstudante"] as! String
                            let ects = data["numero_creditos"] as! Int


                            var uc = UnidadeCurricular (ucName: ucNome, ucSigla: ucSigla, ucIdMapSiges: ucIdMapSiges, anoCurricularIdMapSiges: anoCurricularIdMapSiges, periodoNome: periodoNome, codigoEstudante: codigoEstudante, ects: ects)

                            ucs.append(uc);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                print("bad json")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

    }

    func getUcs() -> Dictionary<String, [UnidadeCurricular]> {
        var listaOfUcs = [String : [UnidadeCurricular]]()

        for u in ucs{
            if listaOfUcs[String(u.anoCurricularIdMapSiges)] != nil {
                listaOfUcs[String(u.anoCurricularIdMapSiges)]!.append(u);
            } else {
                var ucName = [UnidadeCurricular]();
                ucName.append(u);
                listaOfUcs[String(u.anoCurricularIdMapSiges)] = ucName;
            }
        }
        return listaOfUcs;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to break down your problem into solvable problems. Your problem is not about authentication, it is specifically about how to send headers along with your http request. search for that in docs or so and you will find a lot of links

Comment: Please look into the docs : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410592-datatask. You need to use `dataTask(with: URLRequest)` method on `URLSession`. When configuring `URLRequest` you can set values for HTTP header fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go you just need to add the header for `Authorization`
Use [Codable](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/codable) for JSON parsing don't use `JSONSerialization` and use this [tool](https://app.quicktype.io/) for converting the `Json` to the `struct`

```
let url = URL(string: "http://209.97.133.56/api/ucs")!
let token = "your token"
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.httpMethod = "GET"


URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response , error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Invalid JSON")
}.resume()
```

**Edit**

Use the tool that I have give to convert your json to the struct, JSON converted by the tool

```
struct UPS: Codable {
    let data: [UPSData]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }
}

struct UPSData: Codable {
    let id: String
    let unidadeCurricularID: Int
    let unidadeCurricularNome: String
    let unidadeCurricularAbreviatura: String
    let unidadeCurricularAtivo: Int
    let unidadeCurricularIDMapSiges: Int
    let anoCurricularID: Int
    let anoCurricularNome: String
    let anoCurricularAbreviatura: String?
    let anoCurricularAtivo: Int
    let anoCurricularIDMapSiges: Int
    let periodoTempoID: Int
    let periodoTempoNome: String
    let periodoTempoAvreviatura: String
    let periodoTempoOrdem: Int
    let periodoTempoAtivo: Int
    let periodoTempoIDMapSiges: String
    let numeroEstudante: Int
    let idAnoLetivo: Int
    let idUnidadeCurricular: Int
    let idEstadoInscricao: Int
    let idAnoCurricular: Int
    let numeroCreditos: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case unidadeCurricularID = "unidadeCurricularId"
        case unidadeCurricularNome = "unidadeCurricularNome"
        case unidadeCurricularAbreviatura = "unidadeCurricularAbreviatura"
        case unidadeCurricularAtivo = "unidadeCurricularAtivo"
        case unidadeCurricularIDMapSiges = "unidadeCurricularIdMapSiges"
        case anoCurricularID = "anoCurricularId"
        case anoCurricularNome = "anoCurricularNome"
        case anoCurricularAbreviatura = "anoCurricularAbreviatura"
        case anoCurricularAtivo = "anoCurricularAtivo"
        case anoCurricularIDMapSiges = "anoCurricularIdMapSiges"
        case periodoTempoID = "periodoTempoId"
        case periodoTempoNome = "periodoTempoNome"
        case periodoTempoAvreviatura = "periodoTempoAvreviatura"
        case periodoTempoOrdem = "periodoTempoOrdem"
        case periodoTempoAtivo = "periodoTempoAtivo"
        case periodoTempoIDMapSiges = "periodoTempoIdMapSiges"
        case numeroEstudante = "numeroEstudante"
        case idAnoLetivo = "idAnoLetivo"
        case idUnidadeCurricular = "idUnidadeCurricular"
        case idEstadoInscricao = "idEstadoInscricao"
        case idAnoCurricular = "idAnoCurricular"
        case numeroCreditos = "numero_creditos"
    }
}
```

Add all of your network request code in this class

```
class NetworkRequest {


    func auth<T: Decodable>(with url: URL, token: String, completion: @escaping (T) -> Void) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response , error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                completion(try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data))
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()

    }


}
```

use this code any where in your class

```
NetworkRequest().auth(with: url, token: token) { (ups: UPS) in
    print("do what do want to you")
}
```

Comment: Ok I got the endpoint with all data.. I think it's ok.. but how can I represent the information on my view now?

Comment: what are you trying to say ?

Comment: I got data array with whole information that I needed.. but now I need to show this "ucs" when I run the app. It still shows the information of my String json

Comment: Look I added a new image to show you.. i run the app but only appears 3 names, I need to show every information of the url